# Convert CSV to ARFF using IKVM and WEKA

Tags: csv, weka, ikvm, arff

```
CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
loader.setSource(new File("));
Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
```

When i run above code in java , it's working fine.

But when i do the same thing in c# using the following code, it throws exception in line

```
weka.core.Instances instsOrg = csvLoader.getDataSet();
```

The exception message  is" The type initializer for 'weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils' threw an exception"

```
 string filename = "myCSVfile.csv"";
 weka.core.converters.CSVLoader csvLoader = new weka.core.converters.CSVLoader();
 csvLoader.setSource(new java.io.File(filename));
 weka.core.Instances instsOrg = csvLoader.getDataSet();

 weka.core.converters.ArffSaver saver = new weka.core.converters.ArffSaver();
 saver.setInstances(data);
 saver.setFile(new File("myCSVfile.arff"));
 saver.writeBatch();
```

I have added weka.dll , IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll and IKVM.Runtime as references files.
Can anyone help me to get rid of this exception please???
Please reply as soon as possible :(

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace and the inner exception?